# How to change default arrow size in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

I tried to change default styles (all of them show now 0.2 cm), but arrows (of all types) keep creating with same width as before (0.3 cm).

Libreoffice 4.2.8.2.

Comment: This is not about programming.

Comment: Why do you use such an old version?

Comment: @thebusybee does it work differently in 7.x versions?

Comment: Isn't that your task to try?